# AWS Beanstalk with htaccess for symlinks / rewrites?

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I just recently setup an aws elastic beanstalk environment, I'm trying to get the rules of my htaccess to work with it. It unfortunately is not.

This is my htaccess file that I'd like to get working.

```
<ifmodule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript text/javascript image/jpg image/jpeg image/png image/gif video/mp4
</ifmodule>

Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^\.]+\.[^\.]+$
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule .* - [L]

RewriteRule ^(\d+\/)?/assets/(.*)$ /assets/$2 [L]
RewriteRule .*$ App/index.php [L]
```

What do I have to do to make this work?

Comment: Can you share more details in your question ?  Where do you include this .htaccess file ?  Which Elastic Beanstalk platform are you deploying to (I guess PHP) ?  Are you in a load balanced environment or single host ?

Comment: Are you deploying a Java app ? Ruby ? Python ?